# Flutter Wrap and runAlignment

Tags: flutter

Can someone show me an example that `runAlignment` take effect in the `Wrap` widget of flutter

In document we have

> How the runs themselves should be placed in the cross axis.
>
> For example, if runAlignment is WrapAlignment.center, the runs are
> grouped together in the center of the overall Wrap in the cross axis.

I don't see any difference, by setting different values of runAlignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried first, I was curious why isn't `runAlignment` working. Then I wrapped my `Wrap` with `Container` and set a `color` and guess what ? `Wrap` widget's height is setup by number of runs.

For example, If `Wrap` have two run, then height of the wrap will equivalent to the child's height multiply by run. Setting `width` and `height` in `Container` allows us to use `runAlignment`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Wrap(
        runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        children: List.generate(20, (i) =>
          RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (){},
          child: Text(' Button $i '),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.green,
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
         )
        )
      )
    ))
    );
  }
}
```